# Selenium WebDriver Fails to Locate Elements on Linux Server but works locally

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, server

I'm experiencing an issue with my web scraper running on a Linux server where it fails to locate elements using Selenium WebDriver. The scraper works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when I run it on the Linux server, it throws a NoSuchElementException.

The error message I receive is:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":".Crom_table__p1iZz"}

I've tried using WebDriverWait to wait for the table to load, but it doesn't seem to be working. Additionally, I've logged the page source on the Linux server and compared it to my local machine, and I've noticed significant differences in the HTML structure.

I am using a custom user-agent to prevent differences, but that hasn't resolved the issue. I'm not sure what else to try to resolve this issue.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
def team_defenses(season):
    url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/defense?Season=' + season
  
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=get_driver_options())

    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the table to load, if it doesn't load display content
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz')))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        with open('error_page_source.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(driver.page_source)
        driver.quit()
        return

    table = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz')

    # ... rest of my code ...

    driver.quit()

def get_driver_options():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # Bypass OS security model
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  # Overcome limited resource problems
    return options
```

Comment: Have you checked python and package version between two environments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded compatible chromedriver.exe for the chrome on my computer. Then I run it with the code I revised below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
```

instead of "ChromeDriverManager().install())" statement i choose my local chromedriver.exe, chrome version should be checked for compatible chromedriver.exe. For more information you can check this website https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection

```
def team_defenses(season):
    url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/defense?Season=' + season    
    chrome_path = "C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_service = ChromeService(chrome_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)

    driver.get(url)
    try: 
        table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Crom_table__p1iZz')))
        print("Table found:", table)
        rows = table.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='.//tbody/tr')
        data = []
        for row in rows:
            row_data = [cell.text for cell in row.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='.//td')]
            data.append(row_data)
        headers = [cell.text for cell in table.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='.//thead/tr/th')][0:-13]
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    driver.quit()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
    return df

team_defenses("2021-22")`
```

[image: Results]